# Coordinates model changed (Autodesk Viewer)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I dont know this is the right place to ask, but since Autodesk redirects here on their 'get help' page, im trying anyway....

We have a couple of autodesk models that we display using their viewer. Also, we had a couple of 'presets' configured: camera positions based on XYZ of the camera and XYZ of the target the camera is looking at. So, when you push the preset, the camera position changes towards the XYZ and the target is set as well.

This worked fine - untill this weekend (23-04-2018): The positions are completely off... E.G. one of the presets did center the viewable area on a specific part of the model and now it seems the model is zoomed out 50 times and in another angle (we are using the perspective camera). I'm not sure what's the cause of this, but if i had to guess, it would be that the parsing of the source DWG is done again automatically and the center of the model as SVG shifted, and thus the stored XYZ coordinates are useless.

Obviously we can reinitialise the presets, but since i dont know what caused this, im unsure if thats just wasted time. Now the question: Does anyone know what is the cause of this and can we avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were indeed some changes that might have affected the scenes that "manipulates" with positioning (be it camera or component).

The scene I usually use to illustrate the component transformations: http://giro-watch.tk/ was "broke" when I updated to the latest Viewer version.

In case you refer to the Forge Viewer lib without specifying the version:

```
... src="https://.../v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.1"></script>
```

as in this case, omitting ***?v=v4.1***,
you will get the latest version of it and since recently the Forge Viewer changed from v3 to v4, some breaking changes were expected. 
However, between you and Autodesk server, might be a couple of services that caches this file and this is why you project might work fine even after the Forge Viewer was updated and just now the caches were cleaned/renewed.

This is why we recommend to [always use versioning in production code](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/forge-viewer-always-use-versioning-in-production-code.html).

Comment: Thanks, found the docs and now indeed specify the version. However, in my case, omiting the version number does/did not return the latest, but the 3.3.5 version. Anyway - applying the version number helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - ok, seems to be related to the version of the viewer - although im still unsure why it switched (there was no new version released afaik) manually specifying

`<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.1.0"></script>`

fixed it.